# Google sheets formula to join 2 tables and calculate percentage

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to create a function that joins 2 tables where there are sellers and other table where there is other type of employees, join them together with the trip number that was made and also a column with the percentage of what was sold according to a table of percentages.

I have a spreadsheet that makes it more clear of the tables and what i am trying to achieve

Any help will be very much appreciated.

[Spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1VAqaJ2oSYJdVtqTchQalfIS1fU5Qo9foT6RZkO3oTxc/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Added formula to your [sheet here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1VAqaJ2oSYJdVtqTchQalfIS1fU5Qo9foT6RZkO3oTxc/edit#gid=1560683547):

```
=index(query({{A2:B,E2:E*xlookup("Seller",J:J,K:K,)/100};lambda(z,map(index(z,,1),index(z,,2),lambda(a,b,{a,b,xlookup(a,G:G,H:H)*xlookup(xlookup(b,M:M,N:N),J:J,K:K)/100})))(index(split(flatten(G2:index(G:G,counta(G:G))&"|"&transpose(M2:index(M:M,counta(M:M)))),"|")))},"Where Col1<>'' order by Col1"))
```

[image]

Comment: Amazing response!